# Finding if a CFG is ambiguous

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I'm trying to find if the following CFG is ambiguous.

\begin{align*}
    M &\to 0R \mid 1R\\
    R &\to 1RR \mid 0 \mid 0M\\
    P &\to 0PP \mid 1 \mid 1M\,.
\end{align*}

When doing the parse tree, do I treat $0R$ as two separate things or as one? 
If I treat all those things as separate, when I get to $0M$, do I go back to the loop of $M\to 0R \mid 1R$ again?

Comment: Your question is very basic. You need to go back to your course materials and textbook, and check the definition of context-free grammars, and what it means for a grammar to produce a particular string. There doesn't seem much point in somebody typing all of those definitions as an answer, because they're already in every textbook. Here, the terminal symbols are $0$ and $1$, and the nonterminal symbols are $M$, $R$ and $P$. I'm not sure what parse tree you're trying to produce, since you've not said what string you're trying to parse, and I'm not sure why the lack of epsilons is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a parse tree, each vertex is annotated by a terminal, non-terminal, or $\epsilon$. In particular, you have to treat $0R$ as two separated things, a leaf labeled $0$ and a vertex labeled $R$. You can have several vertices with the same label, corresponding to your "loop".

I suggest looking at some examples of parse trees on the web or in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Finding whether an arbitrary context free grammar is ambiguous is undecidable. That's meant, in general. But on a case by case basis, there are techniques you can use to show how a grammar is ambiguous, when it is so. As others have suggested, textbooks will give you the basics about those. But even textbooks vary in pedagogical quality or completeness of explanations. You can also back up to other resources, such as Wikipedia articles, of varying quality, just the same, granted. In your case, the grammar is simple (read: small) enough to use a common, simple technique: find a string in the language which admits more than one leftmost derivation, aka parse tree. And you're done once you find it: because, then, yes, the grammar is ambiguous.

And from only the phrasing of your question, I suspect you have already found its answer, actually. :)